# Convert a .txt file in a .csv with a row every 3 lines

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, text-processing, csv

Let's say I have a txt file like this:

```
Mario
mario@me.com
+399038259953
Luigi
luigi@live.com
+395902385093
Yoshi
yoshi@yahoo.com
+81293565291
```

[and so on for 300 lines...]

How do I make a .ods (or .xls, or .csv, it does not matter) file which has three rows (name, email, phone number)?
I need it so I can easily convert it in a .vcf file and bulk save these numbers in my phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `paste` to make a `csv`:

```
 paste -d,  - - - < file
```

Output:

```
Mario,mario@me.com,+399038259953
Luigi,luigi@live.com,+395902385093
Yoshi,yoshi@yahoo.com,+81293565291
```

Comment: ... or ... `pr -3tas, < file` ...

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my day!

Comment: @bac0n Separate answer, so it can be voted on?

Comment: ... There is a third, I just can't find it...